# Roslyn analyzer: Is class marked as partial

Tags: c#, roslyn-code-analysis, partial-classes, csharp-source-generator

Is there a way to find out whether class is `partial` inside Roslyn analyzer?
There is a `PartialImplementationPart` in `IMethodSymbol`, but nothing similar for `INamedTypeSymbol`.

I'm writing a Source Generator, and I want to generate second part of the class only if it's possible (if first part is partial).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the Modifier List to check if the class is partial.

```
var isPartial = classDeclaration.Modifiers
                                .Any(m => m.IsKind(SyntaxKind.PartialKeyword));
```

Comment: This does not answer the question: how to get this from an `INamedTypeSymbol`?

Comment: I got errors about lambda expressions. I needed to use `classDeclaration.Modifiers.Any(SyntaxKind.PartialKeyword);`. You didn't specify above but in my case classDeclaration is a `ClassDeclarationSyntax`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `INamedTypeSymbol`, you need to check its declarations in syntax:

```cs
typeSymbol.DeclaringSyntaxReferences.Any(syntax => syntax.GetSyntax() is BaseTypeDeclarationSyntax declaration && declaration.Modifiers.Any(modifier => modifier.IsKind(SyntaxKind.PartialKeyword))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at `ISymbol.Locations` if you only have access to the `ISymbol` - more than one location is a pretty good indicator that it's a partial class.